# will not show login page in swift

Tags: ios, swift

this is my code for login page that work correctly:

```
func doLogin(username: String, password: String) {

    let parameters = [
        "NationalCode": username,
        "password": password
    ]
    let url = "http://home/login"
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody).responseJSON { response in

        if let data = response.data {
            let json = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.nonLossyASCII)
            if json=="0"{
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "error", message: "wronge username or password", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "try", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                return
            }
            else{
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginToMain", sender: self)
                })
                let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                guard let dictionary = jsonData as? [String:String] else { return }
                print(dictionary["name"])
            }
        }
    }
```

when i click login button, i go to next page.
now how can i say the app do not show login page for next running until i log out??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save `token`, which you will get from server side. Or smt else what provide server.

There is method `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` in `AppDelegate`, where you can implement initial `viewController`

```
if (token.isExist) {
    self.window?.rootViewController = viewController
} else {
    self.window?.rootViewController = loginViewController
}
```

For saving token you can find opensoure lib, or just use `UserDefaults`

for save:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(token, forKey: "MyTokenKey")
```

for get:

```
let token = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "MyTokenKey")
```

for remove:

```
UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "MyTokenKey")
```